# adding profile picture to database on Flask

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

There is a registration form. How to add a profile picture to the database and get it back immediately. I know that it is possible to with `AJAX`, but I don't know how to implement it. I can send name of image to database with `BLOB` type, but can't print my image on profile page. What is the problem?

`Registration code:`

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        email = request.form['email']
        filenames = request.files['files']

    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
    filenames = []
    for file in uploaded_files:
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
            filenames.append(filename)
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(filename) VALUES (%s)',(filename))
    # This line is essential, store the data in session
    session['filenames'] = filenames

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        session['email'] = email
        session['firstname'] = firstname
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (firstname, lastname, email))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))
```

`profile.html:`

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('profile.html', data=data, filenames=filenames)
```

`register.html:`

```
<input type="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
<input type="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="First name">
<input type='file' name="files" id="uploadPDF">
<button>Register</button>
```

`profile.html:`

```
<h2>Welcome, {{ firstname }}</h2>

{% for file in filenames %}
  <h1>{{ file }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you say get it back immediately I'm assuming based on your code you mean that after they have registered their account you redirect them to their profile page and when they are redirect their picture should show up on the first visit and they don't have to refresh or have to wait for some time before the picture is available. If I'm wrong please correct that information in your question.

So you have multiple things you need to do here.

A. How will you store these pictures. There are two (easier) ways of doing this.

1. Storing the binary data of the picture into your database with a column type of blob
2. Saving the picture with a long random name to avoid conflicts to the hard drive where you store static files then save that picture's random name and a reference to which user it belongs to in the database. **This option is by far the easiest when you get to the next section**

B. Based on which one of those you did you now have to retrieve the image when they navigate to their profile

1. When they navigate to their profile you have to add a url to an endpoint on your sever  that has some way of being passed which user picture you need. Then fetching the binary data from the database and returning that data as a file.
2. When they navigate to their profile, grab their user id. Query the database for which profile picture is for that user and grab the random name you generated. Since this file is saved in your static files folder you can just add the static folder url with that random name appended to the end. For example that url could look like this `https://example.com/static/somerandomlongnameforthispicture.jpg`

http is very basic/strict on how things can be retrieved from the server. Now if you're wanting to use ajax for this as in they are on their profile page already and they updated their picture and you want to show that update immediately then the logic I explain for storing the file is the same but you will have to update the url for the `<img>` tag you have in your html to point to the file name your server makes for that new picture. Or just force a refresh and let your server side template handle the update.

Comment: yes, you understood it correct, but I don't know how to write a code for this issue.

Comment: could you please check question again? I have updated it

Comment: That code is a great start. I can't say I've ever seen someone save a filename in a session variable before but as far as I know that shouldn't have any security issues so long as it not the whole path to the file. However I'm guessing it doesn't show an actual image but just the name of the image correct? That's fine if you're just prototyping. When it comes time to show the image make sure to use the url function for grabbing static files. You are doing great so far though as far as writing the code for this problem. Keep it up.

Comment: Also make sure that you save that secure_filename in the database somewhere and have the user id linked to that file. For instance if the person logs out and the session gets destroyed how do you grab the profile image for them when they relogin? Just a helpful scenario to think about.

Comment: the deal is that code not working. I can not realize why(

Comment: In your code I don't see where you store the file name in the database. I only see user info being stored.

Comment: could you please check it again?

Comment: Looks like you're storing it now. I will say you're SQL statements looks off, I don't know your database schema so I can't help too much there. However I'm guessing it still doesn't work. Reason being is in your `profile` endpoint you are passing in `filenames` but that endpoint doesnt have access to `filenames` cause that variable is defined in `register`. Don't store the filenames in a list. Just query the database inside of `profile` to retrieve the filenames. Yes it's slower than a list but this is more scalable and less prone to python global bugs.